# Click a button that is visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several buttons in div in an html page , I want to click the buy button which is visible in viewport , when I press the key B.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 66) {
    //click the visible buy button in viewport , 
    $(".buy").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="buy">BUY</div>
  <div class="buy">SELL</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="buy ">BUY</div>
  <div class="buy ">SELL</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="buy ">BUY</div>
  <div class="buy ">SELL</div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note : there are 100's of buy button , but only 1 buy button appears at a time in viewport

Comment: Please describe your problem clearly, what you are expected out is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other `.buy` buttons **are invisible really**, you can try this:

```
 $(".buy:visible").click();
```

Else, get your visible section by this:

```
 var myVisibleSection = document.elementFromPoint(x+10, y+10);
```

(The x and y are position of parent of your `sections` that is matches with visible section and you can get them by jquery (`.offset()`) or vanilla js. 10's are sum of border and padding of the parent.)

Now:

```
myVisibleSection.find(".buy").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this convenient function which tells us if the button is visible in the viewport, which I found in this [blog](https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2). Also please make the css class `sell` which is the same as `buy` and set it for the sell `div's`, since we need to distinguish between the two buttons!

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 66) {
    //click the visible buy button in viewport , 
    $(".buy").each(function( index ) {
      if($(this).isInViewport()){
      console.log($(this).html() + " - " + index);
        $(this).click();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="buy">BUY</div>
  <div class="sell">SELL</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="buy">BUY</div>
  <div class="sell">SELL</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="buy">BUY</div>
  <div class="sell">SELL</div>
</section>
```

Comment: what about jquery :visible , does your answer has any benefits compared to visible ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams I like his solution more than my answer :) I cant think of anything!

Comment: no , his solution clicking all the elements with buy class , even though its not visible in viewport